# Convergence of a recursion

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Given a sequence $(x_n)$, such that $0 \leq x_n \leq 1, \forall n$. Further, $0 \leq x_n \leq f(x_{n-1})$ and $f(x)$ is bounded above and below, monotonically decreasing or increasing (depending on a parameter)and bounded. I know that this implies that the sequence $y_n$ which is bounded above and below, defined as $y_n = f(y_{n-1})$ converges. But can anything be concluded about the convergence of (given) sequence $(x_n)$?

Comment: No there exists a sequence and a function satisfying this condition such that the sequence doesn't convergence. In particular you can take $f(x)=1$ and obviously there exists a system $x_n$ that does not converge.

Comment: Something isn't right. Let $x_n=0 \forall n$ and $f(x) = 2x$ then let $y_0=1$, $y_n=2^n$. Then $y_n$ meets the conditions but doesn't converge.

Comment: How do you conclude that the sequence $y_n$ converges?

Comment: I think he means bounded $f$ every monotonicaly sequence convergence to a limit (maybe infinity)

Comment: @peterwhy Banach fixed point theorem i think.

Comment: @Fightclub1995 idontseethepoint above gave an example. Or maybe 
$$x_0  = 0.9\\
f(x) = x^3\\
y_0 = 1.1$$

Comment: @idontseethepoint and peterwhy, the sequence $y_n$ and the function $f$ is bounded above as well. I suspect if f has a unique fixed point which is the lower (if f is decreasing) bound of the sequence ($x_n$) then ($x_n$) converges. However, nothing can be said if f is increasing.

Comment: @Fightclub1995 f need not necessarily be a contraction map.